# Can I have a default.aspx page in an MVC site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms

I've got a legacy WebForms site with a Default.aspx page that's configured in IIS to be the default page.  So when someone goes to `mysite.com` they *see* `mysite.com/Default.aspx`, but the url in the address bar only shows the `mysite.com`.

I added MVC to the site, and I want to gradually move functionality to MVC.  Everything works, but it broke the root page: navigating to the route caused a 404 because the default route was matching the root and trying to route a the Home controller, but there wasn't one.  So I added one that does this:

```
' GET: /Home
Function Index() As ActionResult
    'jump to the go page
    Return Redirect("/default.aspx")
End Function
```

This now works, except that when you navigate to the route, it shows `mysite.com/Default.aspx` in the address bar.

I'd like it if either:

- I could NOT match the root route, and let the WebForms `Default.aspx` page handle it as before
- I could route as I'm doing now, but make it so the Default.aspx page was not displayed in the address bar.

Are either of these possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

In your route configuration, remove the controller in the defaults parameter.
From this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

To this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then add the `Default.aspx` to your project root