# ASP.NET MVC4 with webforms Default.aspx as the start page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

I had an ASP.NET MVC4 app with the following routing defined in the Global.asax.cs. The app's start page is Index.cshtml view that is returned from the action method Index() of the Home controller. I then added a legacy ASP.NET WebForms app that had Default.aspx as the start page. How can I make this Default.aspx page as the start page of this integrated MVC+WebForms app:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}.mvc/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = "" }
              );


              routes.MapRoute(
              "Root",
              "",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
            );


        }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try the following in your Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // Web Forms default
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "WebFormDefault",
        "",
        "~/default.aspx"
    );

    // MVC default
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                          // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",       // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // parameter default
    );
}
```

Also I don't think you'll need the `.mvc` portion of the `Default` route.

Comment: I think we are close. The start page is now `Default.aspx`. But the action links are not working.: E.g: `@Html.ActionLink("Show me...", "Index", "TestController");` sends back to the home page, and the URL in the browser is showing: `http://localhost/myProject/?action=Index&controller=Test`

Comment: @nam try altering the `Default` route, as above. Generally when the `@Html` helper's return a link with the path in the query sting it means it can't find a suitable route to map to.

Comment: I reversed the order of the "Web Forms default" and the "MVC default" blocks of your solution above and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Removing 'controller = "Home"' from defaults parameter worked great for me. I found that solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21213711/9793076.

Change the defaults parameter from:

```
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

to:

```
new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

The current solution breaks the routing of MVC links as @nam said.