# ASP.NET relative url changes after first login and logout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, webforms, relative-url

In my ASP.NET MVC 4 app that was integrated with an exiting ASP.NET 4 Webforms app, the home page is Default.aspx that has a relative link as: `<a href="myApp/Account/Login.aspx">Click here to login</a>`. When I click on the link, it correctly opens the login.aspx page. But after I login and then logout and then click on the same link to login again, I get the error: `"The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /myApp/myApp/Account/Login.aspx"`. As you notice that this time the URL added an extra myApp in the path. I could see this changed path in the status bar even when I hover over the link after I had logged in and logged out: `http://localhost/myApp/myApp/Account/Login.aspx`

On the other hand if I close the browser and then open it again and go to my app and hover over the login link, I can see the correct url in the status bar as: `http://localhost/myApp/Account/Login.aspx`. And I can click on the link and can login.

Why the relative URL is changing when I login and logout and don't close the browser? I'm using IE10 and Chrome 33.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say why without to see more code, but it's a bad practice to hard code the url string, you are better to generate it:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("abc", new { action = "Login", controller = "Account" })">Click here to login</a>
```

Comment: the Default.aspx is home page that came from the legacy ASP.NET webforms app and hence is not using any controller or views. ASP.NET MVC was integrated to the legacy ASP.NET Webform app. It seems that after user logs in the MV routing part takes over the integrated app and is messing up the relative URL. I have defined the routing in Glogal.asax.cs as shown here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819051/asp-net-mvc4-with-webforms-default-aspx-as-the-start-page)